# Usar o mesmo click event pra varios Buttons em C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click

Estou fazendo um projeto em C# usando WPF, que possui muitos botões. Existe alguma forma de identificar qual botão foi clicado para não precisar fazer um click_event pra cada Button?

Comment: Você pode ter somente um button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) e dentro do evento, identificar o botão através de alguma propriedade, por exemplo o e.Content

Comment: Cara, li totalmente errado. Acho que tô com mt sono D=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim.

Você usa o objeto `sender` para descobrir qual foi o botão que chamou o evento.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    var button = (Button)sender; //Aqui será instanciado o botão que chamou o evento

    // A partir daqui você pode usar uma propriedade, para saber qual foi o botão que chamou o evento.
    // Eu costumo definir uma tag para o botão e usá-las nesses caso, algo como:

    if(button.Tag == 1){
        // fazer algo
    }

    // Mas também pode ser usada a propriedade Name

    if(button.Name == "btSalvar"){
        // fazer algo
    }

}
```

Comment: Valeu, Era isso mesmo que eu precisava! =D

Comment: Que bom que ajudei =D